# error "sh: dpkg-deb: command not found" number 127

Tags: macos, applescript, dpkg

`error "sh: dpkg-deb: command not found" number 127`

My full code is

```
  tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    display dialog "Enter the Folder Name. It must be on your Desktop" default answer ""
    set debID to text returned of the result
end tell

do shell script "cd ~/Desktop"
do shell script "dpkg-deb -b " & debID
```

Please tell me how to fix the error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop"
do shell script "dpkg-deb -b " & debID
```

to:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop ; /usr/local/bin/dpkg-deb -b " & debID
```

(or whatever the appropriate path to `dpkg-deb` is).

Comment: Now I am getting error "dpkg-deb: failed to open package info file `com.test/DEBIAN/control' for reading: No such file or directory" number 2

Comment: OK - I see the second problem - your `cd` does not persist between calls to `do shell` - answer updated to fix this.

Comment: Now getting 
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed to exec tar -cf: No such file or directory

dpkg-deb: subprocess tar -cf returned error exit status 2" number 2

Comment: OK - at this point you should probably debug the shell stuff separately, in Terminal, then when you've ironed out the problems with paths etc you can try getting it to work in AppleScript.

Comment: The command works fine in terminal, except there cannot be a space between ~/Desktop/debID

Comment: OK - I've updated the answer one last time - if this doesn't work then I'm stumped.

Comment: @user3756109: If variable `debID` may can contain spaces, you must use `& quoted form of debID` instead (which is good practice in general). Note, however, that an initial `~` will then not be expanded to your home folder (you'd have to do that in AppleScript beforehand).